# Homebrew is not found on apple silicon

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-silicon

I have just installed brew on my new laptop but when I try and run brew its tells me there is no such command. What could I be doing wrong?

```
tomsmail@MacBook-Air ~ % brew
zsh: command not found: brew
```

I have fully installed brew along with the necessary xcode terminal commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run:

```
echo $SHELL
```

If your shell shown is zsh, do this:

```
echo "eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)" >> ~/.zprofile
```

If yor shell is bash, run this:

```
echo "eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If the result is csh, run this command:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv >> ~/.cshrc
```

Answer (score 4):

Running the bellow command should solve the issue

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Answer found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/413207

Answer (score 2):

Go to Terminal: paste one by one.

1. `echo "eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)" >> ~/.zprofile`
2. `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`
3. `brew` [you will get the details of home brew]